# workflow 4 performance workflowinvoker

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4

We have lots of workflow in our system.

We notice that using WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(myworkflow) was taking almost a 1 sec to execute. The workflow is a bit big, but in our test, it was doing nothing. myworkflow was build from the XAML with ActivityXamlServices.Load

Any suggestion in how to improve this?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you always calling Load and passing the freshly loaded Activity instance to the WorkflowInvoker? Some sample/pseudo code that demonstrates you exact steps each time would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try caching the activity instance you pass to the invoker - http://www.neovolve.com/post/2010/07/23/Caching-workflow-activities-to-increase-performance.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps u are using custom activities in tour workflow which are not well writen? Remember that the cachedmetadata is called very often

Comment: in my case we have the XAML version stored in our DB. Then it gets retrieved then we loaded via ActivityXamlService ... is there a way to invoke the validation before invoking the workflow? to make WorkflowInvoker.Invoke be faster ? Kind of skip the validation process in the WorkflowInvoker.Invoke

Comment: But are u using custom code or native activity's or just out of the box? As far as i know it is not possible to skip the cachemetadata foreach existing activity, and that doesn't matter much anyway. Your own activity's can be a problem

Comment: yeah we have lots of custom activities, can you explain why this would be a problem? Thanks

Comment: be carefull with making database connections etc inside your own custom activity's, if u have to do it then do it in the execute or else do it in the designer. Just don't make connections in the cachemetadata, that's what we've done wrong in the past making things slow.